# Web API: Insufficient Privileges on Private Projects

Tags: sonarqube

**Configuration Details**

We have a SonarQube 6.7.2 (build 37468) on-premise installation running.

The instance is accessible from our office IP **without** HTTP Basic Auth, as well as from everywhere else **with** HTTP Basic Auth.

The "Force user authentication" option is off.

All projects are set to private - in case someone gets past the HTTP Basic Auth.

My user belongs to the sonar-administrators groups and has "Browse" and "See Source Code" permissions on all projects.

Using the web interface in the browser, I am able to see all projects including analysis results etc., as expected.

**Problem**

However, using the Web API, I receive "Insufficient Privileges" errors on several API calls.

My user has a valid token that I pass to cURL [as described in the documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API). I even created a new token, to be sure I'm not using an invalid one.

**Example**

```
$ curl -X GET -u my_user_token: https://sonar.example.org/api/measures/search_history?component=the_project&metrics=lines_to_cover%2Cuncovered_lines%2Ccoverage&ps=1000
{"errors":[{"msg":"Insufficient privileges"}]}
```

**Question**

Is it not possible to retrieve measures information or project information via the API for projects that are set to private?

The above call works fine if the project is to public. (But then again, if the project is set to public, that call works fine even without authentication.)

We do have the same issue when using the SonarLint plugin for PHPStorm. The plugin works fine as long as the projects are public, but server sync stops working as soon as projects are set to private.

I'm thinking maybe it would be best to deny all requests to SonarQube except from our whitelisted office IP and have everyone connect via VPN if they want to access the instance from their home office. That would allow us to make all projects public and not have any of these issues. Is that the recommended way to run an on-premise installation of SonarQube?

Comment: First, you should use the "private" features only for authorisation management, and not to get a more secure server. 

Then, about the "Insufficient Privileges" message when using WS : do you confirm that you have no issue in the UI ? 
If yes, are you sure you are using the same user ?

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam Thank you for your feedback. Yes, I do not have any issues using the UI and I am using the same user. If we set the projects to public, every unauthorised user can freely browse the projects. We didn't find an option to restrict access for guest users, other than setting "force user authentication" to "on". But doing that broke our builds in Jenkins, because the scanner could no longer access SonarQube.

Comment: I think we should focus on one problem at a time : on my side what I'm trying to understand is why in the UI you're able to access to private project but you can't when you're using WS. How do you execute your WS call ?

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam Hey, thanks for your feedback. Sysadmin has just granted me access to the server and I found out that the nginx reverse proxy dropped the Authorization header before passing on the request to SonarQube. Having fixed that, the WS calls now work as expected. Thanks again for your help, it's much appreciated!

Comment: Good news ! Could you please add an answer to your question ? It would allow to not set this question not having any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the SonarQube instance was running behind an nginx reverse proxy that dropped the `Authorization` HTTP header from the request before passing it on to SonarQube.

After fixing the nginx configuration, all Web API calls work as expected.